# Flask with Fetch API and render_template - receive new rendered data

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, fetch-api

In my `Flask` project from input field I'm getting with `JS Fetch API` typed value by user and then I'm passing it to my Python function, where depending on user input I do different things.

Everything work correctly. JavaScript getting value, Flask sees it.

JS Code:

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let token = new FormData();
    token.append('search', document.getElementById('search_place').value);
    const request = async() => {
        const response = await fetch('/stop', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: token,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            mode: 'cors'
        }).then((tables) => {
            $('.table').html(tables);
        });
    };
    request();
});
```

With Flask every user input I want to change content in templates:

```
return render_template('view.html', tables=[pd.DataFrame.to_html(df, index=False, justify='justify-all')])
```

So user give new value then after 'Refresh' button click everything should be new inside templates.

**I don't know how I should receive with Fetch API response from Flask, with new rendered data.**

I'm trying with:

```
.then((tables) => {
            $('.table').html(tables);
        });
```

without any success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const request = async() => {` - you're not **return**ing anything here ... so `}).then((tables) => {` `tables` will be undefined here ... and fetch is usually like `fetch(....).then(response => response.text()).then(result => here is the result of the fetch)`

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for your answer! Maybe you want explain me this topic in question?

Comment: huh? you want me to explain your question? [here's some documentation for fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you're not using fetch correctly at all
- you're setting a cors response header in a request
- `mode: 'cors'` is the default for cross origin requests, but
- you're request is same origin, so why are you messing with CORS anything
- no need to create that function or use async await

So

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let token = new FormData();
    token.append('search', document.getElementById('search_place').value);
    fetch('/stop', { method: 'POST', body: token })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(tables => $('.table').html(tables));
});
```

but if you insist on using async/await

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const token = new FormData();
    token.append('search', document.getElementById('search_place').value);
    const response = await fetch('/stop', { method: 'POST',body: token} );
    const tables = await response.text();
    $('.table').html(tables));
});
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo (missed a > in a =>)

Comment: a little confused here...response.text() will yield the page html, not the html from the 'tables' variable he is passing..am i mistaken?

Comment: @mike01010 - `response.text()` returns a Promise that resolves to whatever the heck the server responds with, and that's what `tables` will contain - or is it `$('.table').html(tables))` that is confusing you? that's jquery - we don't talk about that any more